# Шок-может быть лишь из-за позитива?

Tags: этимология, лексика, терминология

Может ли шок быть позитивным,иметь положительный характер?
Мой учитель по русскому языку,при разборе одного из заданий пробного ЕГЭ, объяснил мне,что шок может носить только негативный характер.Т.е. нельзя быть шокированным из-за чего то приятного,позитивного.Так ли это? 
(к слову,вот тот самый вариант из задания ЕГЭ.
В предложении "Меня шокировало прекрасное выступление детей,..." нарушена лексическая норма)

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, терпеть не могу модное выражение, особо любимое блондинками (не по цвету волос, а по IQ), по любому поводу "я в шоке". Шок - это тяжелое состояние, наступающее от сильнейшего психологического или физического потрясения.
Поэтому, думаю, в данном случае уместнее сказать "приятно удивлены" или, если необходимо усилить, "приятно поражены".

Answer (score 1):

"Прекрасное выступление детей", действительно, не может шокировать, оно может только радовать, приводить в восторг, доставлять удовольствие и наслаждение.

Чтобы убедиться в этом, нужно обратиться к толковому словарю

ШОК, [франц. choc - удар, толчок]
1.Состояние общей подавленности организма (при травме головного мозга и т.п.)
 Травматический ш. 
2.Состояние крайней растерянности или подавленности. Нравственный ш. Нервный ш. От этого известия все были в шоке.

ШОКИРОВАТЬ, [от франц. choquer], переносное значение.
Вызывать чувство неловкости, приводить кого-л. в смущение своим поведением, нарушением правил приличия, общепринятых норм поведения. Ш. гостей своими речами. Ш. окружающих своим поведением. Вас не шокирует мой наряд?

Есть еще русский вариант слова "шокировать"  - это "потрясти", также в переносном смысле.

ПОТРЯСТИ. Сильно взволновать, произвести большое впечатление. П. до глубины души. Красота моря потрясла меня. Всё его существо было глубоко потрясено. Рассказ потряс наше воображение. Певец просто потряс зрителей своим исполнением.

Однако "однозначно прекрасное" выступление потрясти также не может. Потрясти может что-то новое, неожиданное, удивительное. Человек еще до конца не разобрался в своих оценках и эмоциях, но все же оценивает их как нечто положительное, вносящее в его жизнь новые впечатления.

Answer (score 1):

Ближайшим синонимом "шокировать" будет "эпатировать". В отличии от "потрясения",которое может произойти самопроизвольно, независимо от воли "потрясающего", шокируют вполне осознано выходя за рамки принятых в обществе норм.  Как правило красивые и тем более прекрасные вещи в рамки общества вписываются и поэтому даже если они удивительны, то они способны потрясти, но не шокировать:

> *Меня потрясли прекрасные вокальные данные Сьюзан Бойл, столь контрастирующие с её внешностью и поведением*.

Замени в данном примере и получится бессмысленность, так как тогда выйдет, что я считаю подобное прекрасное пение на сцене неприемлемым в обществе, но если так, то почему оно прекрасно?

Так что значит прекрасное не может шокировать? Отнюдь. Если по каким-то причинам что-либо прекрасное в обществе непринято выставлять напоказ, а показали:

> Меня шокировала прекрасная обнажённая девушка стоящая на улице.

Также прекрасное может шокировать,  если услышишь его в обществе, где нормы о прекрасном, сильно расходятся с твоими. Скажем прекрасное исполнение русской песни от русскоязычного в России не удивит, а услышав тоже самое от представителя племени Тумба-юмба в глухой Амазонии лёгкий шок испытать можно, хотя это не отменяет прекрасность исполнения.

Что касается конкретного примера:

> Меня шокировало прекрасное выступление детей

То мне сложно представить такую ситуацию, когда это может шокировать. Хотя если эти дети выступают в стриптиз-клубе клубе или эту сцену этого представления режиссёр вставил в конец фильма наподобие "Трудно быть Богом" Германа-ст., то прекрасное выступление детей может и шокировать, хотя в 99% случаев шокировать прекрасным действительно невозможно.